# Node.js - How to input successively using spawn or exec?

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, spawn

I'm making a web-app-deployment-platform using heroku API.
In order to use heroku API, It needs login using heroku CLI. I made docker image installed heroku CLI So, I'm trying to login to heroku on docker using nodejs.

Heroku login is command to login to heroku in heroku CLI. It needs successive inputs. (email and password)

```
heroku login
> Email: (you need to input email then password)
```

But my code below doesn't work.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

login: function(req, callback) {
    var result = "";
    var heroku_login = spawn('docker', ['exec', '-it', 'my container name', 'heroku', 'login']);

    heroku_login.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
    heroku_login.stdin.write(req.heroku_email);
    heroku_login.stdin.write(req.heroku_pwd);

    heroku_login.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        result += data.toString();
        console.log(result);
    }

    heroku_login.stdout.on('end', function() {
        callback(null, result);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for my English skill. If you don't understand my word please give me a comment.

Comment: I have a similar question. It looks like there are no answers yet; but if by chance you've resolved this yourself; could you post an answer?

Comment: @Neil I have resolved by calling the http api. `exec('curl -nX GET https://api.heroku.com/apps -H "Accept: application/vnd.heroku+json; version=3" -H "Authorization: Bearer ' + api_key + '"' , function(err, stdout, stderr) { ...`
`

Comment: Cool. I ended up resolving my issue by checking `data` in `child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {...` & then calling `child.stdin.write(...)` from within that check.

Comment: @Neil Hate to awaken a long-since dead horse to be beaten again, but would you mind putting this in a formal answer so it doesn't go over looked? It's easy to overlook the solution when it's hidden in a comment, for those of us landing on a dozen or more SO questions from googling :D

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to read the `stdout` of your executed `child`. You can then write your next inputs using `child.stdin.write('data')`.

A more complete example to demonstrate this:

```
const child = exec("leetcode user -l", (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    child.stdin.end();
  }
});

child.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  if (data.includes("login:")) {
    child.stdin.write(`${pref.leetCodeUsername}\r\n`);
  } else if (data.includes("pass:")) {
    child.stdin.write(`${pref.leetCodePassword}\r\n`);
  } else if (data.includes("Successfully")) {
    callback(data);
  }
});

child.stdout.on("message", (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Here I'm executing the CLI command for a Leetcode login using `leetcode user -l`. Log an error to the console if there is one, otherwise, end using `stdin.end()`.

Then, read your `stdout` using `child.stdout.on("data", (data) => { ... });`
Here you could add in your successive inputs, or flex your input based on what your `stdout`'s `data` contains. In my case, I "write" the username if the current prompt is for the username, or password if its the password prompt. Link to the complete code: https://github.com/1nv1n/code-goes-here/blob/master/src/leetcode/leetCode.js#L23

Adding this as an answer so this question doesn't go overlooked when something useful is hidden away in a comment, per @Swivel